# Pandoc Lua filter: How can I check in function Str if argument comes from a title (of a chapter or section)

Tags: lua, pandoc

actually, i do some filtering for the markdown to LaTeX transformation. I use lua filters for this. Now i'd need to do something like this:

```
function Str (el)
  if is_in_a_title(el) then
    -- do this
  else
    -- do that
  end
end
```

meaning that inside Str i want to check if the argument belongs to a chapter/section title. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Re-posting what I wrote on the mailing list:

This is best done by running sub-filters:

```
local header_filter = {
  Str = function (el)
    -- do this
  end
}

function Header (h)
  return pandoc.util.walk_block(h, header_filter)
end
```

The `header_filter` is just like a normal Lua filter. The [`walk_block`](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#pandoc.walk_block) function applies that filter to all elements below the Header, and those elements only.

---

More recent pandoc versions allow to use the `walk` method on blocks; with those, the above can be written as

```lua
function Header (h)
  return h:walk {
    Str = function (el)
      -- do this
    end
  }
end
```